# Define a custom InjectionResolver for @Inject

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

My goal is to add some additional logic around the System Injection Resolver (to decorate it, so to speak). Basically, I want to register a custom injection resolver (e.g. described [here](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/custom-resolver-example.html)), but for the `javax.inject.@Inject` Annotation. The setup works if I create a different custom annotation, but not when using @Inject. My implementation is as follows:

Injection Resolver:

```
@Singleton
@Rank(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class InjectInjectionResolver
    implements InjectionResolver<Inject> {

    private final InjectionResolver<Inject> injectionResolver;

    @Inject
    public InjectInjectionResolver(
            @Named(InjectionResolver.SYSTEM_RESOLVER_NAME) final InjectionResolver<Inject> injectionResolver) {
        this.injectionResolver = injectionResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolve(final Injectee injectee, final ServiceHandle<?> root) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Why is this never called?");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() {
        return injectionResolver.isConstructorParameterIndicator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator() {
        return injectionResolver.isMethodParameterIndicator();
    }
}
```

And I register the resolver as follows (inside `ResourceConfig`):

```
register(new AbstractBinder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(InjectInjectionResolver.class).to(new GenericType<InjectionResolver<Inject>>() {}).in(Singleton.class);
        }
    });
```

What I tried so far:

- using `@Rank`
- using both the `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder` or `org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder` with `TypeLiteral`, along with implementing the `org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver` or `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionResolver`
- making sure the same setup works with @CustomAnnotation (where both the constructor and the resolve methods are called)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Versions used: jersey 2.27

EDIT: When I @Inject the InjectionResolver itself, it seems that hk2's `org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver` is injected for the `org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver`, while my custom injection resolver is injected for `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionResolver`. However, the custom injection resolver is *not* used for injection.

Comment: Have you tried setting the rank of your InjectionResolver for the javax inject to something > 0 ?  That'll force it to be used in favor of the system provided one

Comment: @jwells131313 Yes and No. I tried it haveing the wrong configuration, and removed `@Rank`when I had the correct configuration... That actually worked when I used the `org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver` and I figured out the rest. Thank you very much.

Comment: could you post what you fixed in your configuration so this question will have an answer?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration works for me, thanks to @jwells131313 for bringing me back on track. I tried to use fully qualified names, else it's probably from the `javax.inject.*` package.

```
@Singleton
@Rank(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
@org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service
public class MyHk2InjectionResolver
    implements org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver<Inject> {

    private final org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver<Inject> injectionResolver;

    @Inject
    public MyHk2InjectionResolver(
        @Named(org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver.SYSTEM_RESOLVER_NAME) final org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver<Inject> injectionResolver) {
        this.injectionResolver = injectionResolver;
    }

    // ... required methods, could just delegate to system resolver

}
```

To register the resolver, we bind it to the correct type (I do it in the ResourceConfig of a jersey application):

```
register(new org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(MyHk2InjectionResolver.class)
                    .to(new org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral<org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver<Inject>>() {})
                    .in(Singleton.class);
        }
    });
```

With this setup, you can keep using the `@Inject` annotation and write some custom injection logic around it, possibly using the default system injection resolver as a fallback.